# No face unlock for the Nexus S?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, face-unlock

I seems to me, that the **Nexus S did not get the face unlock feature with ICS**?

Why would this not be supported for the Nexus S? Is it the hardware?

I wonder because the code is open source and I assume any other competitor would not restrict this feature just because it's not perfect yet. I mean: There are still quite a few other things that also do not work perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct: starting Ice Cream Sandwich (ICS) 4.0.1 and until the curent *(at the time of writing)* 4.0.3 the **Face Unlock** feature is **not available** to any version of **Nexus S** (NS).

[This thread on **xda-dev**](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1396340) provides various *speculations* as to why Face Unlock is not available on NS:

1. lower quality front camera hardware on the NS
2. the [vulnerabilities](http://www.theverge.com/2011/11/12/2556893/ice-cream-sandwich-face-unlock-feature-fooled-by-a-photo) of this feature
   *(check out the note on the setting that says that Face Unlock is low-security and experimental)*
3. having this feature exclusively available for Galaxy Nexus

*Bottom line:* Face Unlock is present in various ported ICS ROMs, but it's reported to be pretty flimsy at the moment.